# Emacs: i-search start search from begining of buffer

Tags: emacs

Emacs 24.5

If I want search some text in buffer I use command **I-search** (C-f). OK. But it's start search from cursor position. But I need to search from begining of buffer.

Of course I can use C-arrow Up to go to the begining of buffer. But I want search automate from begining of buffer. Is this a possible?

**Edit**

Example:

```
11111111

22222222

33333333

...

11111111

44444444 (cursor here)

11111111

66666666

11111111
```

I want when start ONLY command I-search and input "11111111" to start search from beginning of the buffer (without any other additional command like M-<). Is this a possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly **get to the top of your buffer with `M-<`**.  Then
start your isearch with `C-s` (is that what you meant when you said
`C-f`?).

Use of `M-<` will place a mark at your current position before the
jump so that you can easily return to it with `C-u C-SPC`.  Searching
(without `C-g` cancellation) also sets a mark.

Or, you could just start searching from where you are, and hit `C-s`
an extra time at the bottom of the buffer to continue wrapping around
to the top.

Or, you could search backward from point (your cursor position) with
`C-r`.

Comment: It's `C-u C-SPC`

Answer (score -1):

There is no built-in functionality (that I could find documented) to do what you propose, but you can easily define some advice to change the default behavior.

```
(add-function :before (symbol-function 'isearch-forward) #'beginning-of-buffer)
```

This isn't particularly elegant (perhaps you would like to return to point when you abort searching, for example?) but demonstrates the concept, and is easy enough to extend if you decide that this is actually what you want.

Comment: My guess is you will ultimately, if not immediately, realize that this is a poor idea.  Perhaps you are actually looking for something like `occur` (`M-s o`)?

Comment: The code does not work.

Comment: Hmmm, I believe I tested it at the time. Let me see if it needs an update when I'm at my computer.

Comment: It might be an Emacs change.

Comment: @Edman Still works for me in Emacs 27.1 on MacOS; which version are you on?